# Why is the shaded area the same as the rectangles area?

Tags: c#

this is my first post so please bear with me. I am super new to C#. I am attempting the following: Write a Console application that allows the user to enter the dimensions required to calculate the area of a rectangle, the area of a circle and then display the area of the shaded shape below.[1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0kkN.png

Here is what I've got so far: 
MY PROBLEM: It works perfectly, although the problem is when I run the program, the only thing that's wrong is the shaded area value that it calculates. It seems to show the area of the rectangle as the shaded area answer. So if I input 10 length and 10 width for the rectangle. The shaded area will be 100 as well as the area. I can't see any problems within my code and I have tried everything I can think of. Would appreciate any help. Thanks <3

```
**Program.cs**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Section_A_Excercise_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            clsCalculate Calculate = new clsCalculate();
            Calculate.CalculateRectangle();
            Calculate.CalculateCircle();
            Calculate.CalculateShaded();
            Console.ReadLine();            
        }
    }
}








clsCalculate.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Section_A_Excercise_2
{
    class clsCalculate : clsVariables
    {
        public void CalculateRectangle()
        {
            string title = @"
               __        __   _                            _   _               _ 
               \ \      / /__| | ___ ___  _ __ ___   ___  | | | |___  ___ _ __| |
                \ \ /\ / / _ \ |/ __/ _ \| '_ ` _ \ / _ \ | | | / __|/ _ \ '__| |
                 \ V  V /  __/ | (_| (_) | | | | | |  __/ | |_| \__ \  __/ |  |_|
                  \_/\_/ \___|_|\___\___/|_| |_| |_|\___|  \___/|___/\___|_|  (_)";

            Console.WriteLine(title);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("To Calculate the Area of a Rectangle:");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a length: ");
            Length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a width: ");
            Width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            AreaofRectangle = Length * Width;
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the rectangle of dimensions " + Length + " by " + Width + " is: " + AreaofRectangle);

        }

        public void CalculateCircle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("To Calculate the Area of a Circle:");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a radius: ");
            Radius = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double AreaofCircle;
            AreaofCircle = (3.14) * Radius * Radius;
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle with radius " + Radius + " is: " + AreaofCircle);
        }

        public void CalculateShaded()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();       
            Console.WriteLine("To Calculate the Shaded Area (Area of Rectangle Minus Area of 
            Circle):");
            ShadedArea = AreaofRectangle - AreaofCircle; 
            Console.WriteLine("The shaded area is equal to: " + ShadedArea);
        }

    }
}















clsVariables.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Section_A_Excercise_2
{
    class clsVariables
    {
        protected int Length;
        protected int Width;
        protected int Radius;
        protected int AreaofRectangle;
        protected int AreaofCircle;
        protected int ShadedArea;

        public int _Width
        {
            get { return Width; }
            set { Width = value; }
        }
        public int _Length
        {
            get { return Length; }
            set { Length = value; }
        }
        public int _Radius
        {
            get { return Radius; }
            set { Radius = value; }
        }
        public int _AreaofRectangle
        {
            get { return AreaofRectangle; }
            set { AreaofRectangle = value; }
        }
        public int _AreaofCircle
        {
            get { return AreaofCircle; }
            set { AreaofCircle = value; }
        }

        public int _ShadedArea
        {
            get { return ShadedArea; }
            set { ShadedArea = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also as a side note, I think the problem is something to do with the data type of AreaofCricle as it has to be double as it can be a decimal. I couldn't figure out how to make the other numbers the double data types. Although this might not even be the problem, just thought I'd note this.

Comment: Change protected int AreaofCircle; in clsVariables to protected double AreaofCircle;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having another

```
double AreaofCircle;
```

in your CalculateCircle() method. You are trying to set the global variable AreaofCircle but instead are setting the AreaofCircle that is local to your method. Also there is nothing wrong with having your variables and methods in one file.

Change `protected int AreaofCircle;` in clsVariables to `protected double AreaofCircle;`

Comment: I did what you said and now I have two errors: Both implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). So I changed those two values to double data type too and it still doesn't work lol. I got a different error with the ShadedArea = AreaofRectangle - AreaofCircle;  
After that, I converted all of the Area of circle, Area of Rectangle and Shaded area all to double data type and got no errors. But the number it spits out still isn't correct. Instead of giving me the area of the rectangle, now it gives me 0 every time xD. Hope you can assist. <3

Comment: You need to convert all the values that will store a double to double too, so:


protected double AreaofCircle;

protected double ShadedArea;

public double _AreaofCircle

public double _ShadedArea


Something like this: https://pastebin.com/eB6SD2ig

Comment: Hi Master, thank you for getting back to me again. I did do this before but I've tried again and the same thing happens. The shaded area comes out as 0 regardless of any of the other values. Many thanks, Luke

Comment: @Super have you tried the code in the pastebin link? That is the entire code needed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Thank you for your help! Basically, the problem was that because I had “double area of circle”, “double area of rectangle” inside my method brackets so it was defining a new variable every time instead of getting it from my variables class. So I removed those and it worked! 
Thank you again!

Comment: If my Answer helped you solve your Problem I would appreciate it if you set that as accepted answer. 

Your answer 

"I had “double area of circle”," 

is exactly what was in my answer:

"You are having another

double AreaofCircle;

in your CalculateCircle() method"